# Splitting Drupal commerce order for easier shipping

Tags: commerce

During shipping we generally need to split the orders based on the availability of the products. Considering the order contains two products but only one product is available, we would like to split the order such that we can ship one product now and we can ship the the product later. Both split orders will contain same address and other details.

Are there any module that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to consider this as order splitting. I'm working on a project currently that will make use of the [Commerce Shipment](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipment) module to handle splitting an order into shipments for fulfillment. It can accommodate either a single shipment per order or multiple if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from @ryan I will consider this as a closure. Can you please share the link to sandbox module that you are working. I can take a look at it and plan around that :)

Comment: I got commit access to the repository I linked above, so I'll be making my updates directly to it.